# Connect to localdb that is created under networkservices with a local build agent from vsts

Tags: sql-server, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a local vsts build agent running which running intergration test on a localdb. This is working fine but if I want to inspect the database there is no way to connect to the database from my user account because the database is ceated under the `network service` account.

I have tried to share and start the local database with

```
sqllocaldb share networkservice mssqllocaldb .\test
Private LocalDB instance "mssqllocaldb" (owner: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) shared with the shared name: ".\test".

sqllocaldb start .\test
LocalDB instance ".\test" started.
```

but connect failed.

```
sqlcmd -S .\test
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
```

What is a easy way to connect to this database with ssms (Sql Server management Studio)

Answer (score 0):

An option is run https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/sysinternals/downloads/psexec and start ssms.

Run psexec from a administrator cmd

```
psexec -i -u "nt authority\network service" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
```